# What are the alternatives to using Meetup.com for managing an in-person community?

Tags: physical-communities, community-organizing

I have built a successful group for B2B sales professionals that now spans several cities.  I started on Meetup.com and for a time it was helpful in getting the group launched.  Now that we are several thousand members, we are feeling the constraints of the platform and that the community, member, and event management features are not conducive for managing a large community with multiple events on a monthly basis. Specifically:

- Flexible ticketing (discount codes, pricing tiers, fee handling)
- Mobile attendance tracking and payments
- Customizable and automated event reminders
- Customizable newsletters
- Member database building
- Member profiles
- Distributed team management
- Chapter specific sites
- Content management system
- Media management (photos, video, audio/podcast)
- Global payments handling
- Online community platform(discussion boards, chat)

Are there alternatives that work for a group with over 10,000 members and multiple distinct chapters (more than 4 groups) and can address the above issues?

Comment: Tip 1: Asking for (alternatives for) software can also be done at [softwarerecs.se] (but don't ask as two SE sites simultaneously). Tip 2: They have specific recommendations when [asking for alternatives](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software). Please [edit] your question accordingly., it does not have enough information right now. Especially *scale for* shoudl have **numbers**.

Comment: The results on Software Recommendations are [not promising](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=meetup). A place that is more topical, such as community building, would in theory be more aligned and more likely to receive a reply.

Comment: I'm not saying you must move it there (it was a *tip*). I **am** saying (and repeating) that you need to write a better question. That's what he second tip was for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have a budget for an online community software, but it sounds like you might be at a point where you can start looking into them.

In a previous role, I managed online user groups who periodically met face-to-face. We used the Higher Logic community platform (full disclosure, this is a former employer), which is able to do all that you mentioned above. I am sure there are other platforms out there that would meet your needs as well!

Best of luck!

Comment: Do you have any examples of such community softwares? My search is coming up with very irrelevant stuff...

Comment: Yes, I would suggest "Higher Logic." This is the only tool that I have used that could potentially meet all your requirements.